# Select a date from date picker using Selenium webdriver

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have a webpage with a textbox field. A calender icon near it. When i click on the calender icon a calender view is displayed. I think its not a jquery calender. Can anyone provide an example to automate this type of date pickers.

Comment: I tried this, which is working,        `driver.findElement(By.id("date button")).click();`                 `WebElement StartdateWidget = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of date cell"));`                       `driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of date cell")).click();` `StartdateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));` `StartdateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("td"));`

Comment: Check this example - http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-automating-custom-controls-datepicker/

Comment: Using jQuery we can as below `((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("$('#DateofEvent').val('10/10/2013')");`

Answer (score 7):

I tried this code, it may work for you also:

```
            DateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd"); 
            Date date2 = new Date();

            String today = dateFormat2.format(date2); 

            //find the calendar
            WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.id("dp-calendar"));  
            List<WebElement> columns=dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("td"));  

            //comparing the text of cell with today's date and clicking it.
            for (WebElement cell : columns)
            {
               if (cell.getText().equals(today))
               {
                  cell.click();
                  break;
               }
            }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can handle in many ways in Selenium.

You can use direct click operation to Select values

or

you can write general xpath to match all values from calender and click on specific date as per requirement.

I have written detailed post on it.

Hope it will help

http://learn-automation.com/handle-calender-in-selenium-webdriver/

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how it is coded but something like this may work:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("datepicker")).click(); //click field
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Next")).click(); //click next month
driver.findElement(By.linkText("28")).click(); //click day
```

Answer (score 1):

This one worked like a charm for me where the date picker just has previous and next buttons and Month and year as texts.

Page objects are as follows

```
    [FindsBy(How =How.ClassName, Using = "ui-datepicker-calendar")]
    public IWebElement tblCalendar;

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//a[@title=\"Prev\"]")]
    public IWebElement btnPrevious;

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//a[@title=\"Next\"]")]
    public IWebElement btnNext;

    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "ui-datepicker-year")]
    public IWebElement lblYear;

    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "ui-datepicker-month")]
    public IWebElement lblMonth;



    public void SelectDateFromDatePicker(string year, string month, string date)
    {

        while (year != lblYear.Text)
        {
            if (int.Parse(year) < int.Parse(lblYear.Text))
            {
                btnPrevious.Clicks();
            }
            else
            {
                btnNext.Clicks();
            }
        }

        while (lblMonth.Text != "January")
        {
            btnPrevious.Clicks();
        }

        while (month != lblMonth.Text)
        {
               btnNext.Clicks();
        }

        IWebElement dateField = PropertiesCollection.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[text()=\""+ date+"\"]"));
        dateField.Clicks();
    }
```

Comment: This is great. But you need to use the PageFacotory.InitElements first. More information here http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/WebDev/UIDevelopment/automated-web-testing-with-selenium-2/

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code for selecting date from Two Jquery calendar like Flight Booking site.

```
    Hashtable h=new Hashtable();
    h.put("January",0 );
    h.put("February",1);
    h.put("March",2);
    h.put("April",3);
    h.put("May",4);
    h.put("June",5);
    h.put("July",6);
    h.put("August",7);
    h.put("September",8);
    h.put("October",9);
    h.put("November",10);
    h.put("December",11);


    int expMonth;
    int expYear;

    // Calendar Month and Year
    String calMonth = null;
    String calYear = null;
    boolean dateNotFound;
    dateNotFound = true;
    expMonth= 5;
    expYear = 2014;

    while(dateNotFound)
    {

        calMonth = driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-month")).getText(); // get the text of month
        calYear = driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-year")).getText();




        if(((Integer)h.get(calMonth))+1 == expMonth && (expYear == Integer.parseInt(calYear)))
        {
            String block="//div[@class='monthBlock first']/table/tbody/tr/td";  // THIS IS FIRST CALENDAR
            selectDate(expDate,block); 
            dateNotFound = false; 
        }
        // parseInt - Converts String to integer and indexof( It will return the index position of String)
        else if(((Integer)h.get(calMonth))+1 < expMonth && (expYear == Integer.parseInt(calYear)) || expYear > Integer.parseInt(calYear))
        {
            String block="//div[@class='monthBlock last']/table/tbody/tr/td"; // THIS IS SECOND CALENDAR


                            selectDate(expDate,block); // PASSING DATE AND CALENDAR
                            dateNotFound = false; // Otherwise it will rotate continuously 
        }
        else if((Integer)h.get(calMonth)+1 > expMonth && (expYear == Integer.parseInt(calYear)) || expYear < Integer.parseInt(calYear))
        {
            System.out.println(" Please enter the date greater than Current date");
            dateNotFound = false;

        }
    }

    }
    //Thread.sleep(3000);


    public static void selectDate(String date,String block) throws IOException
    {

                    String monthblock=block;

        List<WebElement> dateWidget = driver.findElements(By.xpath(monthblock));    

        for (WebElement cell: dateWidget)
        {
            //Selects Date
            if (cell.getText().equals(date))
            {
                cell.findElement(By.linkText(date)).click();
                break;
            }

        }

        //Doubt : How to verify the expected results and how to sort the program



        driver.findElement(By.id("SearchBtn")).submit();

        //driver.quit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

http://seleniumcapsules.blogspot.com/2012/10/design-of-datepicker.html

1. an icon used as a trigger;
2. display a calendar when the icon is clicked;
3. Previous Year button(<<), optional;
4. Next Year Button(>>), optional;
5. Previous Month button(<);
6. Next Month button(>);
7. day buttons;
8. Weekday indicators;
9. Calendar title i.e. "September, 2011" which representing current month and current year.

Answer (score 0):

I think there will be different ways to select a Date for different Date picker formats.
For a Date Picker where you need to select a year and month from a dropdown and then pick/click a Date,
I wrote the following code.

```
private void setupDate(WebDriver driver, String csvRow) throws Exception {
    String date[] = (csvRow).split("-");
    driver.findElement(By.id("flddateanchor")).click();
    new Select(driver.findElement(By
            .cssSelector("select.ui-datepicker-year")))
            .selectByVisibleText(date[0]);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    new Select(driver.findElement(By
            .cssSelector("select.ui-datepicker-month")))
            .selectByVisibleText(date[1]);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.linkText(date[2])).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

I got the cssSelector part by the Selenium Firefox IDE. Also, my Date(csvRow) is in (2015-03-31) format.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It would be good to avoid the `Thread.sleep(1000)` calls by using class WebDriverWait.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidy solution where you provide the target date as a Calendar object.

```
// Used to translate the Month value of a JQuery calendar to the month value expected by a Calendar.
private static final Map<String,Integer> MONTH_TO_CALENDAR_INDEX = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
static {
    MONTH_TO_CALENDAR_INDEX.put("January",  0);
    MONTH_TO_CALENDAR_INDEX.put("February",1);
    MONTH_TO_CALENDAR_INDEX.put("March",2);
    MONTH_TO_CALENDAR_INDEX.put("April",3);
    MONTH_TO_CALENDAR_INDEX.put("May",4);
    MONTH_TO_CALENDAR_INDEX.put("June",5);
    MONTH_TO_CALENDAR_INDEX.put("July",6);
    MONTH_TO_CALENDAR_INDEX.put("August",7);
    MONTH_TO_CALENDAR_INDEX.put("September",8);
    MONTH_TO_CALENDAR_INDEX.put("October",9);
    MONTH_TO_CALENDAR_INDEX.put("November",10);
    MONTH_TO_CALENDAR_INDEX.put("December",11);
}

        // ====================================================================================================
        // setCalendarPicker
        // ====================================================================================================

        /**
         * Sets the value of specified web element while assuming the element is a JQuery calendar.
         * @param byOpen The By phrase that locates the control that opens the JQuery calendar when clicked.
         * @param byPicker The By phrase that locates the JQuery calendar.
         * @param targetDate The target date that you want set.
         * @throws AssertionError if the method is unable to set the date.
         */

        public void setCalendarPicker(By byOpen, By byPicker, Calendar targetDate) {

            // Open the JQuery calendar.
            WebElement opener = driver.findElement(byOpen);
            opener.click();

            // Locate the JQuery calendar.
            WebElement picker = driver.findElement(byPicker);

            // Calculate the target and current year-and-month as an integer where value = year*12+month.
            // The difference between the two is the number of months we have to move ahead or backward.
            int targetYearMonth = targetDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 12 + targetDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int currentYearMonth = Integer.valueOf(picker.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-year")).getText()) * 12
                    + Integer.valueOf(MONTH_TO_CALENDAR_INDEX.get(picker.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-month")).getText()));
            // Calculate the number of months we need to move the JQuery calendar.
            int delta = targetYearMonth - currentYearMonth;
            // As a sanity check, let's not allow more than 10 years so that we don't inadvertently spin in a loop for zillions of months.
            if (Math.abs(delta) > 120) throw new AssertionError("Target date is more than 10 years away");

            // Push the JQuery calendar forward or backward as appropriate.
            if (delta > 0) {
                while (delta-- > 0) picker.findElement(By.className("ui-icon-circle-triangle-e")).click();
            } else if (delta < 0 ){
                while (delta++ < 0) picker.findElement(By.className("ui-icon-circle-triangle-w")).click();
            }

            // Select the day within the month.
            String dayOfMonth = String.valueOf(targetDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            WebElement tableOfDays = picker.findElement(By.cssSelector("tbody:nth-child(2)"));
            for (WebElement we : tableOfDays.findElements(By.tagName("td"))) {
                if (dayOfMonth.equals(we.getText())) {
                    we.click();

                    // Send a tab to completely leave this control.  If the next control the user will access is another CalendarPicker,
                    // the picker might not get selected properly if we stay on the current control.
                    opener.sendKeys("\t");

                    return;
                }
            }

            throw new AssertionError(String.format("Unable to select specified day"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

here i show you my orignal code for automating jqueryui calender from its official site "https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/default.html".

copy paste the code and see it working like charm :)

vote up if you like it :)
regards
Avadh Goyal

---

```
public class JQueryDatePicker2 {
static int targetDay = 0, targetMonth = 0, targetYear = 0;

static int currenttDate = 0, currenttMonth = 0, currenttYear = 0;

static int jumMonthBy = 0;

static boolean increment = true;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String dateToSet = "16/12/2016";

    getCurrentDayMonth();
    System.out.println(currenttDate);
    System.out.println(currenttMonth);
    System.out.println(currenttYear);

    getTargetDayMonthYear(dateToSet);
    System.out.println(targetDay);
    System.out.println(targetMonth);
    System.out.println(targetYear);

    calculateToHowManyMonthToJump();
    System.out.println(jumMonthBy);
    System.out.println(increment);

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\avadh.goyal\\Desktop\\selenium-2.52.0\\web driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to(
            "https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/default.html");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='datepicker']")).click();

    for (int i = 0; i < jumMonthBy; i++) {
        if (increment) {
            driver.findElement(
                    By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/a[2]/span"))
                    .click();
        } else {
            driver.findElement(
                    By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/a[1]/span"))
                    .click();
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);

    }

    driver.findElement(By.linkText(Integer.toString(targetDay))).click();

}

public static void getCurrentDayMonth() {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    currenttDate = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    currenttMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    currenttYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}

public static void getTargetDayMonthYear(String dateString) {
    int firstIndex = dateString.indexOf("/");
    int lastIndex = dateString.lastIndexOf("/");

    String day = dateString.substring(0, firstIndex);
    targetDay = Integer.parseInt(day);

    String month = dateString.substring(firstIndex + 1, lastIndex);
    targetMonth = Integer.parseInt(month);

    String year = dateString.substring(lastIndex + 1, dateString.length());
    targetYear = Integer.parseInt(year);

}

public static void calculateToHowManyMonthToJump() {

    if ((targetMonth - currenttMonth) > 0) {
        jumMonthBy = targetMonth - currenttMonth;

    } else {
        jumMonthBy = currenttMonth - targetMonth;
        increment = false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please do not copy-paste the same answer to multiple questions. Also, asking for upvotes goes against the etiquette here.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work properly to get the current date from the calendar.

```
String today=getCurrentDay(); //function 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("here xpath of textbox")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
WebElement dateWidgetForm= driver.findElement(By.xpath("here xpath of calender"));
List<WebElement> columns = dateWidgetForm.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

    for (WebElement cell: columns) {
      String z=cell.getAttribute("class").toString();
      if(z.equalsIgnoreCase("day")){
      if (cell.getText().equals(today)) {
        cell.click();
        break;
      }
    }

private String getCurrentDay() {
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
 //Get Current Day as a number
 int todayInt = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
 System.out.println("Today Int: " + todayInt +"\n");

 //Integer to String Conversion
 String todayStr = Integer.toString(todayInt);
 return todayStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver;

public void launch(){

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.cleartrip.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    System.out.println("The browser launched successfully");
    }
public void clickdate(String inputDate){
    WebElement ele =driver.findElement(By.id("DepartDate"));
    ele.click();
    String month = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='monthBlock first']/div[1]//span[1]")).getText();
    String year = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='monthBlock first']/div[1]//span[2]")).getText();
    System.out.println("Application month : "+month + " Year :"+year);
    int monthNum = getMonthNum(month);
    System.out.println("Enum Num : "+monthNum);
    String[] parts = inputDate.split("/");
    int noOfHits = ((Integer.parseInt(parts[2])-Integer.parseInt(year))*12)+(Integer.parseInt(parts[1])-monthNum);
    System.out.println("No OF Hits "+noOfHits);
    for(int i=0; i< noOfHits;i++){
    driver.findElement(By.className("nextMonth ")).click();
    }
    List<WebElement> cals=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='monthBlock first']//tr"));
    System.out.println(cals.size());
    for( WebElement daterow : cals){
    List<WebElement> datenums = daterow.findElements(By.xpath("//td"));
    /*iterating the "td" list*/
    for(WebElement date : datenums ){
    /* Checking The our input Date(if it match go inside and click*/
    if(date.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(parts[0])){
    date.click();
    break;
                          }
                     }
                 }
}

public  int getMonthNum(String month){
    for (Month mName : Month.values()) {
    if(mName.name().equalsIgnoreCase(month))
    return mName.value;
    }
    return -1;
    }

public enum Month{
    January(1), February(2), March(3), April(4), May(5), June(6) , July(7), August(8), September(9), October(10), November(11),December(12);
    private int value;

    private Month(int value) {
    this.value = value;
    }

    }


public static void main(String[] args)  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Cleartrip cl=new Cleartrip();
    cl.launch();
    cl.clickdate("24/11/2015");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an argument for keeping it simple and stupid if the date picker comes from a simple html5 input and the goal is to test whatever events were added to the test. Consider for example:

```
<input type=date name=mydate />
```

and one wants to set a test where 'mydate' is hardcoded to 02/22/2017, a solution with python is to use the following code, which is simple enough to debug to observe what it does:

```
def setdate(elem_name, date_str):
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name('mydate')
    elem.click()
    elem.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT)
    elem.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT)
    elem.send_keys(date_str)

setdate('mydate'', '02222017')
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do

```
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  js.executeScript("document.getElementById('id').value='1988-01-01'");
```